# Power BI Distinct Count Over Multiple Columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

How would I count rows in a power bi query where the two columns have a different combination, but sometimes repeat the same combination (to result in a higher count)?

I tried using countx, but cannot figure out how to calculate different combinations and scenarios.

example: (i'm trying to generate column d but cannot figure out powerbi logic to generate)
column D should count the number of scenarios that are the same in columns, a, b, an c.

```
| Column A | Column B |Column C |Column D |
| a        | 1        |3        |2
| a        | 1        |3        |2
| b        | 1        |3        |1
| a        | 2        |3        |2
| c        | 1        |3        |3
| c        | 1        |3        |3
| a        | 2        |3        |2
| c        | 1        |3        |3
```

or based on the above source data simply generate (desired end product)

```
| Column A | Column B |Column C |Column D |
| a        | 1        |3        |2
| b        | 1        |3        |1
| a        | 2        |3        |2
| c        | 1        |3        |3
```

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your base table named Table.

[image]

In PowerBI, add a new table and paste the following code.

```
Table 2 = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Column A], 'Table'[Column B], 'Table'[Column C]), 
    "Column D",
    CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'))
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the power query for your requirement. Go to the **Advanced Editor** of your table and add the code I written after "//New code starts from here".

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSlTSUTIEYmOlWB10XhKGnBGcl4wil0ycylgA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Column A" = _t, #"Column B" = _t, #"Column C" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column A", type text}, {"Column B", Int64.Type}, {"Column C", Int64.Type}}),
    
    //New code starts from here
    Grouped_Table = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Column A", "Column B", "Column C"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Column A","Column B","Column C"}, Grouped_Table, {"Column A","Column B","Column C"}, "Grouped_Table", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Grouped_Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Grouped_Table", {"Count"}, {"Grouped_Table.Count"})
in
    #"Expanded Grouped_Table"
```

You have to change the **previous step name** in the first line after "//new code starts here" I have written in the above code.

And here is the output-

[image]